# React higher order component over a built-in DOM element class

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I've made a HOC wrapping form inputs

```
const Input = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return <input {...this.props}/>
    }
})

const Field = fieldHoc(Input)

const element = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <Field name="username" id="form-field-1"/>
).getDOMNode()
```

Can I somehow skip the `createClass(...)` part for declaring my own `Input`? What's the React class of `React.DOM.input` element? (I'm using React 0.13.3)

Instead of the own `Input` class I tried passing both the `React.DOM.input` and the `React.createFactory('input')`. That doesn't work, triggering the following warning message:

> Warning: bound createElement(...): No `render` method found on the
>   returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`
>   in your component or you may have accidentally tried to render an
>   elementwhose type is a function that isn't a React component. Warning:
>   Don't set the props property of the React element. Instead, specify
>   the correct value when initially creating the element.

Comment: `const Input = props => (<input {...props} />);` EDIT: sorry, stateless functional components seem to have been introduced in 0.14 :(

Comment: @pawel yep, exactly